# Which is the most appropriate mfc control to use while creating a dialog window to modify values in a database?

Tags: user-interface, dialog

I have to modify existing entries in a database. My Addition entry dialog uses edit controls in order to get values and a submit button to update in database.

I have the need to create a modify dialog that should be able to modify entries when needed by user. Is there appropriate mfc control that can be used for my task?

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to edit directly on the list control, you can use CListCtrl or CMFCListCtrl.

I think MFC does not provide a list control for editing directly. So, if you want to do it, consider using a 3rd party, like the free [Ultimate Grid](http://YourUserMessageHandlerFunction).